# I am having trouble while running npm install command

Tags: node.js, npm, vagrant

**I have an error while running npm install and npm run dev commands. i run npm install and get an error as follows:**

```
npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js
npm ERR! dest /home/vagrant/www/laravel/node_modules/.bin/parser
npm ERR! errno -71
npm ERR! EPROTO: protocol error, symlink '../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js' -> '/home/vagrant/www/laravel/node_modules/.bin/parser'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2020-09-12T09_30_14_511Z-debug.log
```

**then i run npm run dev and get this error :**

```
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
 requireStack: [
   '/home/vagrant/www/laravel/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js',
   '/home/vagrant/www/laravel/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js',
   '/home/vagrant/www/laravel/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js'
 ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2020-09-12T09_30_54_849Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
```

**any idea?**

Comment: behind a proxy?

Comment: Are you running this on a Linux VM on a Windows host with file sharing turned on?

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:laravel]?!

Comment: @Quentin sorry i'm new in coding, i edited my question.

Comment: Are you running this on a Linux VM on a Windows host with file sharing turned on?

Comment: Yes. this is what i did. I am working on a laravel project and in my project directory (VM is on)  i run these commands and got errors.

Comment: That's the problem. npm detects it is running on Linux, tries to create symlinks, then fails because the file system is shared from Windows which doesn't support symlinks.